# adding onclick attributes on anchor

Tags: c#, attributes, anchor

I am trying to adding onclick attriubutes on anchor tag in this way

```
chq.Attributes["Onclick"] = "http://172.17.0.221:81/CheckVerification1.aspx?id=" + Session["U_EMAIL"].ToString();
```

This is my anchor tag

```
<a id="chq" runat="server"  target="_blank">Cheque</a>
```

But this way is not wokring can any one give alternative method to do this

Comment: Do you want to add the attribute from the code behind?

Comment: Yes I want to get session email id as querystring to another page

Comment: No need to add `onclick` attribute. best way is to use `src` attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this..

```
chq.Attributes["src"] = "http://172.17.0.221:81/CheckVerification1.aspx?id=" + Session["U_EMAIL"].ToString();
```

**Html**

```
<a id="chq" runat="server" src="" target="_blank">Cheque</a>
```

Comment: Try using `chq.Attributes.Add("src", "http://172.17.0.221:81/CheckVerification1.aspx?id=" + Session["U_EMAIL"].ToString());`

Comment: @user1645793 :: what are you getting as the value of `src` attribute after the page renders while using the first solution?

Comment: I am Using above Code On Page Load Event But This almost not working

Comment: @user1645793 :: change `src` to `href`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be redirect when the onclick event fire you have to use **src** attribute of the anchor tag, at the code behind you can add attributes to raw html elements this way.

```
 chq.Attributes.Add("src", "http://172.17.0.221:81/CheckVerification1.aspx?id=");
```